# Joomla - Website showing blank screen now

Tags: joomla, joomla3.6

I have configured joomla 3.6.x and I have enabled, disabled some module/component. Website stop suddenly, I dont have any clue to resolve it. Could anyone help me out.

Comment: Active component form db or reinstall site

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to do in case of the white blank screen is enable the error reporting.

Open the `configuration.php`, serach for the `error_reporting` and change it to `maximum`. PHP errors are now visible and you should have some idea about what is wrong. If for example a extension is not found, you can enable it again via the database.